# Доступ к Tomcat Manager

Tags: java, tomcat

На выделенном сервере установил tomcat.
Захожу по адресу IP или по домену (установил в **server.xml** 80-й порт), все как надо, страничка открывается.
Хочу зайти в `server status`, `manager app`, `host manager` - вижу ошибку **403**.
В гугле лишь подсказки по добавлению пользователей в tomcat-users.xml, но это не помогает. Добавил несколько пользователей с разными role, одну со всеми сразу, и все равно 403 ошибка, после ввода логина и пароля. В чем проблема?

**tomcat-users.xml**: (без всех стандартных комментариев)

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin,admin_gui,manager,manager_gui,manager-status"/>
  <user username="manager" password="managergui" roles="manager_gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: @MikhailVaysman 9, но могу поставить любую другую, мне не это важно :)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman все отлично работает, разместил свой сайт, перехожу по адресу своего домена, и так далее, но вот менеджер не работает и выдает ошибку после ввода логина и пароля. Если ввести неправильные логин или пароль - будет ошибка unauthorized.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да уже раз 20 перезагружал, пока делал все, что мне необходимо :) Есть пользователи для каждой роли отдельно, и пользователь со всеми ролями сразу, и все равно не заходит.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman https://pp.userapi.com/c638321/v638321565/36133/lIpmYgv08aM.jpg

Comment: @MikhailVaysman хорошо, добавлю в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в названии роли у пользователя. Вместо **manager_gui**, должно быть **manager-gui**, а вместо **admin_gui**, должно быть **admin-gui**. Не подчеркивание, а тире (дефис).

Comment: Хорошо, почему тогда проблема с остальными ролями? Заходил через пользователя с одной ролью "admin", была та же ошибка.

Comment: Копипастил, сейчас попробую по новому.

Comment: вроде получилось, не знаю правда, почему изначально было не так, ибо я копипастил, сам не писал и не мог ошибиться :)

Comment: Вы не могли бы еще подсказать, я в server.xml поставил обработку только 80 порта, никаких alias и virtual host нет, но я упорно по адресу mydomain.com попадаю на сайт, хотя этого быть не должно?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Задал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655923/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA-tomcat, время горит, прошу прощения, что напрямую обращаюсь :) Просто последние несколько дней задаю вопросы на тему серверов и томката, и Вы первый, кто откликнулся :)

Comment: UPD: разобрался, опять не с того сайта копипастил)

Answer (score 0):

У вас в роли записано так:

**<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>**

Соответственно эти же имена используются в секции **user** Более подробно можно почитатать по [ссылке](https://www.javase.ru/Koty_i_virtualnye_hosty/)

Comment: Пожайлуста давайте развернутый ответ а не только ссылку на странице с ответом.